# STM32 Cube IDE: When I change something on the .ioc file and code is generated, what other files are changed?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I am using STM32 Cube IDE. I am making a change on the .ioc file, on the Configuration tab. E.g. let's say I am enabling interrupts on a certain pin. When I save the file, the IDE asks me if I want code to be generated, on which I click yes. I understand that this code generation alters some files, e.g. main.c, by writing its own functions etc. What is the list of all files that code generation might change?

I am asking this since I want to know which files to commit on my GitHub branch when I make a change on the .ioc Configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using version control. So start from a clean state.

Make a change to the .ioc file, and regenerate code.

Then get your version control software to tell you what has changed.

For git: git status

Answer (score 0):

most importantly, ensure all your code is between the user code blocks:
e.g.:

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

// Your code must be in here to be kept through ioc regeneration

/* USER CODE END Includes */

// Your code out here will be lost